# How can we use RepoDB with code first approach?

Tags: asp.net-core, orm, migration, ef-code-first, code-first

If we want to create an Asp.Net Core project with code first approach and using RepoDB, how can we manage the operations such as migrations? Do we need an additional ORM like EF, EF Core?

Thanks.

Comment: If you must use code first,you need ORM like EF Core in asp.net core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RepoDb does not support code first migration, it is highly recommended to use EF for your scenario. Or, you can also use some migration tools to manage your DB migration (ie: Evolve, Fluent Migrator, etc) and use RepoDb as your ORM.

Comment: We are researching. Thanks.

Comment: It is also an option to combine both ORM.

Comment: I agree. This was the meanest option for us. Thank you.